# Android Soundpool VS Vibrator

Tags: android, soundpool, vibration

I have to let the Smart phone vibrate and simultaneously play a sound.

I tried something like this:

```
soundPool.play(sID, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0,1.0f);
vibrator.vibrate(90);
```

The Problem is that the Phone vibrates instantly but the soundpool starts with a little delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vibrator.vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%5B%5D,%20int%29) method. 
The first value in the pattern array indicates the number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to wait. Both feedback types have to start instantly!

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/1QOMyoJU7bU

Comment: I found it by myself a while ago. No solution for me I always test on hardware. The mysterious thing is: Galaxy Nexus S has no delay, HTC desire has delay. But I have to use the Desire because of the stronger vibrator...